# But, Except, than + Infinitive with 'to' or without 'to'?

Tags: verbs, infinitives, bare-infinitive

I have read that after '**but**', '**except**', '**than**', *bare Infinitive* (i.e., Infinitive without 'to') is used. 
But I am confused which one is correct:
(1) We want nothing *but to be free*. 
OR, We want nothing *but be free*.
(2) Better to reign in Hell *than to serve in Heaven*.
OR, Better to reign in Hell *than serve in Heaven*.
(3) He does everything *except/but finish* his homework.
OR, He does everything *except/but to finish* his homework.
Please clarify it with proper grammatical rule.

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that after *but, except, than,* bare Infinitive (i.e., Infinitive without *to*) is used.

- Parenthetically (People always say they have read, or have heard, or a friend told them, about these rules, but they never say where or who. Very curious. Is there a Deep State Grammar that keeps ELU questions coming?)

This is a rather silly rule and does not state anything correctly. You should not trust the source.

First, grammar doesn't work like that. It's not a matter of words on a string, with everything depending on the word before it. It's much more like tracking your thoughts, with many things happening simultaneously, forming multi-dimensional matrices. Linear it ain't.

Second, the type of complementizer used in a clause (like infinitive, with or without *to*) is generally dependent on the verb (or predicate adjective) that governs the complement clause. It is **not** governed by adverbs or conjunctions.

Third, *but, except,* and *than* are all quite different. *But* means the same as *and*, with an added presupposition of surprise. *Except* is a negative trigger, and *than* only occurs in comparative constructions, which involve two quantifiers and a negative.

These constructions all have very peculiar syntax, depending on the context and the verbs they're used with. The words mentioned shouldn't be considered alone -- they mean little or nothing alone; they're just part of the construction machinery -- and grammatical rules should not be based on random words, only on constituents and constructions.

Comment: But it is not clear which ones of the given sentences are correct.

Comment: Yes, because there is no special rule, the sentences are out of context, and you can't teach English one sentence at a time.